# Help with finding an encryption scheme and comparator

Tags: optimization, cryptography

I need some help to figure out what to Google...

So I need to design an optimization problem and we came up with a fantastic premise but it hinges on the following;

Say I have a decrypted string like so (note, it could be any string like a stringified array or JSON object etc.):

```
This is my super secret secret that only people with the full key can decrypt
```

What encryption/decryption scheme can I use to allow participants do decrypt a part of the secret string with only a partial key?

So say the encryption key is:

```
Super secret key
```

And the participant has figured out a part of the key like:

```
Supper secret code
```

Then they should be able to decrypt the secret key into something like:

```
Thus&w3*7^@super secret secret t%a(8)ytle=p#eple%@#45UEi$5L& @3w*dn/d@3$5pt
```

i.e. some partial correct decryption of the initial secret.

I also need a way to provide the participants with a way to compare their decrypted secret to the actual decrypted secret without giving them the full, decrypted secret. Something that they can use to optimize their decryption. I'm guessing something in NLP.

I just need some terms to Google here, I'll do the rest.

Please and thank you!

Comment: One time pad might work.